# How does Windows install a Python package, with command prompt?

Tags: python, pip, path, python-py

I have read quite a few helpful suggestions/instructions for installing packages. This is not a problem for me now. But it makes me curious why some of the commands would work (installing a package for me) while others wouldn't.
For example, if I want to install the basic package "numpy" in Python -
Assuming the correct path
When I type

- "py -m pip install numpy" it works; but
  When I type
- "pip install numpy" it doesn't work!
  Why is this?

Also, what are the reasons behind how one should select the correct path anyways? Note I'm not asking the "how" but why certain paths work vs. other wouldn't.

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ and https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html (especially section about "Python launcher for Windows").

Comment: It is not specific to Python or pip. It is all about how executables are found on Windows (Unix/Linux, etc. are pretty much the same on this). You need to read up on the `PATH` environment variable, what it is for and how to use it.